# How to know which file in /dev/input/event* represent for touch input device

Tags: touchscreen

I have a raspberry pi3 and one 7" official lcd and have code to get data from touch input, but when I plug a keyboard into the RPI the touch device is event2, and event0 when keyboard is unplugged. So how do I determine which event is represent for touch?

Answer (score 2):

Look at `/dev/input/by-id` and `/dev/input/by-path`, or check out the output of `lsinput`, or

```
udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/input/eventX
```

Note that `xinput` seems to use its own IDs which don't always correspond to `/dev/input/eventX`.

Answer (score 1):

install:

```
apt install input-utils
```

and issue

```
lsinput
```

this will list all your input devices along with some information about each device